# Caching results using Massive micro-ORM

Tags: c#, caching, massive

I'm using the Massive micro-ORM with a new project.  I added some caching, and it all appeared to work - until I realize that the cached objects (dynamic) are still querying the database.  This kills the whole point of caching.

What would be the easiest way to *disconnect* the result set from the database. Nearly all calls are read-only.

I'm using code like this to query records:

```
public static dynamic GetActive()
{
    return Caching.LoadFromCache("Units_GetActive", 120,
        () =>
        {
            dynamic tbl = new Units();
            return tbl.Find(Enabled: 1, orderby: "SortOrder");
        });
}
```

My caching code looks like this:

```
public static dynamic LoadFromCache(string cacheKey, int secondsToCache, Func<object> query)
{
    object tocache = null;

    // result will always get the value here
    // tocache will only have the value when it was pulled from our method
    object result = MemoryCache.Default[cacheKey] ?? (tocache = query.Invoke());

    if (secondsToCache > 0)
    {
        if (tocache != null) // only save to cache if it wasn't there
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, tocache, DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(secondsToCache));
    }
    else
    {
        // remove from cache only if secondsToCache was zero or less
        MemoryCache.Default.Remove(cacheKey);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The caching code **works**.  The problem is the dynamic object returned (`IEnumerable<dynamic>`) opens another connection to the database.

Ideas?

Comment: A guess (not familiar with this particular ORM): put the results of the enumerator into a list (call `ToList()`), so that it won't be enumerated every time it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim Medora had the right idea.

I changed my caching code to this:

```
public static dynamic LoadFromCache(string cacheKey, int secondsToCache, Func<object> query)
{
    object tocache = null;

    // result will always get the value here
    // tocache will only have the value when it was pulled from our method
    object result = MemoryCache.Default[cacheKey] ?? (tocache = query.Invoke());

    if (secondsToCache > 0)
    {
        // If this came from Massive, we need to get the list instead of opening a 
        // database connection each time we enumerate.  I check the type, because other things
        // are stored.
        if (tocache is IEnumerable<dynamic>)
        {
            tocache = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)tocache).ToList<dynamic>();
            result = tocache;
        }

        if (tocache != null) // only save to cache if it wasn't there
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, tocache, DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(secondsToCache));
    }
    else
    {
        // remove from cache only if secondsToCache was zero or less
        MemoryCache.Default.Remove(cacheKey);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The `ToList<dynamic>()` was the key part.  It seems to work as expected now. `ToList<T>` is an extension method in the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: NO ! You're cluttering your cache object with disguised db logic. Convert it to a list in your data-access code, before putting the results in cache. Just put .ToList() at the end of the lambda?